# I am getting error as value of java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

my JSONResponse looks as follows

[["1","somevalue","1234567890","1239876093","some"],   ["2","somevalue","1234567890","1234567890","some"]]

and code accessing it is as follows

```
            try{
                String[] details = {""};
                JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(response);
                JSONArray array = array1.getJSONArray(0);
                JSONObject object;
                //print(array.length() + "");
                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    details[i] = object.getString("roll") + "   " + object.getString("name");
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(details));

                    ArrayAdapter<String> defaulters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShowDefaulters.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                    listView.setAdapter(defaulters);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                print(e.getMessage());
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get jsonarray on object array. example:

```
private void test(){
        String json_text ="[[\"1\",\"somevalue\",\"1234567890\",\"1239876093\",\"some\"], [\"2\",\"somevalue\",\"1234567890\",\"1234567890\",\"some\"]]";
        try{
            JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(json_text);
            JSONArray array = array1.getJSONArray(0);
            Log.e("ARR", array.toString());
            JSONArray user_arr = new JSONArray(array.toString());
            for(int i=0; i< user_arr.length(); i++){
                Log.e("USER", user_arr.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
          Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

or:

```
 private void test(){
        String json_text ="[[\"1\",\"somevalue\",\"1234567890\",\"1239876093\",\"some\"], [\"2\",\"somevalue\",\"1234567890\",\"1234567890\",\"some\"]]";
        try{
            JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(json_text);
            JSONArray array = array1.getJSONArray(0);
            Log.e("ARR", array.toString());
            JSONArray user_arr = new JSONArray(array.toString());
            Log.e("USER", "roll: " + user_arr.get(0).toString());
            Log.e("USER", "name: " + user_arr.get(1).toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
          Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```